# How can I dual boot Windows 7 with Windows 10 by replacing Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, operating-systems

I already have a dual boot of Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 in a different partition. I have replaced lots of Linux distributions earlier by formatting the partition and installing the new OS in it. But is it possible to do the same with Windows 10?

I have also heard about the Grub errors which are caused by completely removing a Linux distribution from a dual boot. If I replace Ubuntu by Windows, can I also encounter such an error?

It would be great if I can do this without messing around with grub and bootloader of my computer. I can't afford to lose the Windows 7 partition. Although I have nothing to worry about in my Ubuntu partition which I know will get formatted.

Comment: Yes, you can. Is your BIOS of type EFI or MBR, or equivalently: Is your system disk of type MBR or GPT?

Comment: I don't know much about BIOS and bootloader but I do see a GUI in boot menu and it is EUFI. I guess that's the same as MBR.

Comment: So I googled a little bit and found out my Boot environment is BIOS based. Does it affect the dual boot process?

Comment: Verify it as described in my answer. MBR will require a different method.

Comment: It is MBR based.

Comment: Can I remove the grub using a system recovery media? How is that possible?

Comment: I added a section for MBR in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EFI BIOS requires a GPT disk, so check first the disk type:
In Disk Management, right-click in the lower pane
the "Disk 0" label, choose *Properties*, and you will see it in the
"Volumes tab" in the "Partition style" entry.

[image]

**Answer for EFI/GPT**

Basically, the EFI BIOS takes care of the boot, using files that it finds in the
EFI partition. The following method is taken from an answer on the post
[Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/963426):

> 1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
> 2. Run `diskpart`
> 3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
> 4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk (the EFI volume will be formatted in FAT, others will be NTFS)
> 5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
> 6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
> 7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
> 8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
> 9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
> 10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
> 11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
> 12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory
>
> Assuming you only ever had two operating systems (Win 10 & Ubuntu) you
>   should now be able to boot directly to Windows without hitting the
>   black grub screen.

You may now be able to install Windows 10, verifying that it chooses the right
partition (by default it will probably offer to upgrade the Windows 7 partition).

As this is a very serious operation and a mistake may destroy the disk,
I suggest taking a backup image of the whole disk before starting.
My favorite tool is 
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).

**Answer for BIOS/MBR**

You need Windows 7 installation disk. Boot it and choose the Repair option.

After checking automatically for start up problems, choose the
Command Prompt option and enter the following commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr  
bootrec /fixboot
```

Enter `exit` to close the Command Prompt and restart your computer.